# How do I get the PR information from a branch that's been merged to master using the Github API?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Say I have branches like `patch-1`, `patch-2`, `patch-3` that were merged to `master` by raising PRs on it (the branches have not been merged). I would like to obtain information like the PR number, the reviews on the PR, of the PR that was used to merge `patch-1` to `master`. How can I do this using the Github API? I've gone through the documentation but I can't seem to find any API that can help me do that.

Answer (score 0):

**NB**: I don't know how to do this via the API!

...but I noticed that GitHub has started providing this information as part of the information it displays about a particular commit. E.g., take a look at https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/a01376a493a755923895893e21ac3ce7e4b12ed2; just below the commit message, you can see a link to the pull request that introduced this commit:

[image]

Furthermore, I can see that information update *after* the page has loaded, which means there is an explicit javascript request being used to fetch that information.  By turning on our browser's development features, we can see exactly what's happening.  In this case, I see a request for:

```
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/branch_commits/a01376a493a755923895893e21ac3ce7e4b12ed2
```

And the value returned from that URL is:

```
    <svg class="octicon octicon-git-branch" viewBox="0 0 10 16" version="1.1" width="10" height="16" aria-hidden="true"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 5c0-1.11-.89-2-2-2a1.993 1.993 0 00-1 3.72v.3c-.02.52-.23.98-.63 1.38-.4.4-.86.61-1.38.63-.83.02-1.48.16-2 .45V4.72a1.993 1.993 0 00-1-3.72C.88 1 0 1.89 0 3a2 2 0 001 1.72v6.56c-.59.35-1 .99-1 1.72 0 1.11.89 2 2 2 1.11 0 2-.89 2-2 0-.53-.2-1-.53-1.36.09-.06.48-.41.59-.47.25-.11.56-.17.94-.17 1.05-.05 1.95-.45 2.75-1.25S8.95 7.77 9 6.73h-.02C9.59 6.37 10 5.73 10 5zM2 1.8c.66 0 1.2.55 1.2 1.2 0 .65-.55 1.2-1.2 1.2C1.35 4.2.8 3.65.8 3c0-.65.55-1.2 1.2-1.2zm0 12.41c-.66 0-1.2-.55-1.2-1.2 0-.65.55-1.2 1.2-1.2.65 0 1.2.55 1.2 1.2 0 .65-.55 1.2-1.2 1.2zm6-8c-.66 0-1.2-.55-1.2-1.2 0-.65.55-1.2 1.2-1.2.65 0 1.2.55 1.2 1.2 0 .65-.55 1.2-1.2 1.2z"/></svg>
    <ul class="branches-list">
        <li class="branch"><a href="/ansible/ansible">devel</a></li>
          <li class="pull-request">(<a title="Merged Pull Request: update configuring ansible-galaxy client" href="/ansible/ansible/pull/64796">#64796</a>)</li>
    </ul>
```

In other words, request `https://github.com/:owner/:repo/branch_commits/:commit` to get information about the pull request that introduced a commit.

That's a nice machine-parseable chunk of HTML that includes the pull request id. There's probably a better way to do this via the API.

Comment: So, I did it a slightly different way. I pull a commit and check all info about it then call another API endpoint to obtain the information about it. It's a longer way to do it, I'm not allowed to parse HTML/XML and it works for now :/